# Universal covering of the complement of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

What is the universal covering of $X=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus(S^1\times\{0\})$?

I've been trying to build a covering map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $X$ via composition of $p:\mathbb{R}^3\to Y$ and $q:Y\to X$ where $Y=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(x,0,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $p(x,y,z)=(x,e^y\cos(z),e^y\sin(z))$ and $q$ is to be found, such that $(Y,q)$ is a covering space of $X$.

Since $(\mathbb{R}^3,p)$ is the universal covering of $Y$, if I found a suitable $q$ then I hope that proving that $(\mathbb{R}^3,q\circ p)$ is the universal covering space of $X$ is not a pain.

Is this a good approach? Is there any better solution?

Comment: The universal cover of $X$ is not homeomorphic, or even homotopy equivalent, to $\Bbb R^3$. To use tools that might be bigger than what you've learned so far, one can calculate $\pi_2(X) \cong \Bbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ as a group - which is, in particular, nontrivial - and note that for $k > 1$, $\pi_k(\tilde X) = \pi_k(X)$ for any covering space $\tilde X \to X$. But $\Bbb R^3$ is contractible and has vanishing higher homotopy groups. If you instead set $S^3 \setminus (S^1 \times \{0\})$ - it is more common in knot theory to consider knots embedded in $S^3$ - your universal cover is $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: So if the universal covering space of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus(S^1\times\{0\})$ is not compact nor homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^3$, then what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^2$. If $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, then their universal covers are homotopy equivalent. The universal cover of $S^2 \vee S^1$ is $\Bbb R$ with a sphere wedged at each integer. So the universal cover of $X$ is homotopy equivalent to that.

In particular, this is *not* homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb R^3$ - some advanced tools show $\pi_2(\tilde{X}) \cong \Bbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ (example 4.27 in Hatcher). So $\tilde X$ couldn't possibly have been homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$, which has $\pi_2(\Bbb R^3) = 0$. I doubt you will find a nice way to write down a space homeomorphic to $\tilde X$; even the universal cover of $S^2 \vee S^1$ above is a bit messy.

Standard in knot theory is to consider the complement of your knot $K$ in $S^3$ rather than in $\Bbb R^3$. Indeed, $S^3 \setminus \{(x,y,0,0) : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2 \times S^1$, so its universal cover is $\Bbb R^3$. Knot complements are always much better behaved in this setting; for instance, the universal cover of a knot complement in $S^3$ is always contractible.

Comment: I got it. I showed that $X$ is homotopically equivalent to $Y=$ a torus with a disk filling the classical middle hole of it. Then the covering space of $Y$ is $\tilde{Y}=$ the connected sum of $|\mathbb{Z}|$ many spheres in such a way that every sphere intersect only two other spheres, and each of such intersection is a closed disk. Then  $\tilde{Y}$  is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ with a sphere wedged at each integer, so both have the same universal cover up to homotpic equivalence. My remaining question is: how to realize that $X$ is homotopically equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$?

Comment: See example 0.8 and 0.9 in Hatcher's book.